# How much space does a default installation of Ubuntu Touch take on mako?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I'm just curious how big Ubuntu's rootfs would be because Nexus 4 has no microsd slot and only 16gb of memory.

Answer (score 2):

On the 8GB Nexus 4 (mako) I use for development that I've recently reflashed:

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ df -h
Filesystem       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk0p23  5.7G  3.3G  2.5G  58% /
udev             935M  4.0K  935M   1% /dev
tmpfs            188M  660K  187M   1% /run
none             4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none             5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             936M   72K  936M   1% /run/shm
none             100M   24K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/mmcblk0p23  5.7G  3.3G  2.5G  58% /data
/dev/mmcblk0p21  828M   95M  734M  12% /system

phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ du -hs ~
1.7G    /home/phablet
```

So if you subtract the 1.7GB of data I have in my home directory, I have about 4.1GB free space after the system image.  So for the 16GB model, you'd probably have around 12GB free to play with.

Those numbers may change a bit as the OS is developed.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Touch#Hardware_requirements , ubuntu touch on tablet requires at least 8GB of space.

Unfortunately, I cannot offer any further insight.